# How to create a custom dialog by clicking listview items and sending valuse to dialog to show?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, dialog

Below is my code, I do not know how to add a dialog to my items in `ListView`.

```
package com.example.bookstore;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Psihology extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView mListView;



    int [] images = {
            R.drawable.alchemist,
            R.drawable.hippie,
            R.drawable.child,
            R.drawable.powerofhabbit,
            R.drawable.kakobituvekupravu,
            R.drawable.metafizikapolneljubavi,
            R.drawable.otemeljumorala,
    };

String[] names = {
"Alchemist - Paulo Koeljo",
        "Hippie - Paulo Koeljo",
        "Child health psihology - Julie Turner",
        "The Power of Habbit - Charles Duhigg ",
        "Kako biti uvjek u pravu - Artur Sopenhauer",
        "Metafizika polne ljubavi - Artur Sopenhauer",
        "O temelju morala - Artur Sopenahuer"
};


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_psihology);

        mListView = findViewById(R.id.listViewPsihology);

        CustomAdaptorr customAdaptor = new CustomAdaptorr();
        mListView.setAdapter(customAdaptor);
    }

        class CustomAdaptorr extends BaseAdapter{

            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                return 7;

            }

            @Override
            public Object getItem(int position) {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public long getItemId(int position) {
                return 0;
            }

            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                View view =  getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.schoollayout,null);
                ImageView mImageView = view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
                TextView mTextView = view.findViewById(R.id.textView);

                mImageView.setImageResource(images[position]);
                mTextView.setText(names[position]);

                return view;
            }
        }



    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu,menu);
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.school:
                Intent intent = new Intent(Psihology.this,School.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                return true;
            case R.id.psihology:
                Intent intentt = new Intent(Psihology.this,Psihology.class);
                startActivity(intentt);
                return true;
            case R.id.philosophy:
                Intent intenttt = new Intent(Psihology.this,Philosophy.class);
                startActivity(intenttt);
                return true;
            case R.id.newWriters:
                Intent intentttt = new Intent(Psihology.this,NewWriters.class);
                startActivity(intentttt);
                return true;
            case R.id.other:
                Intent intenttttt = new Intent(Psihology.this,Other.class);
                startActivity(intenttttt);
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


}
```

So my question is: How can I show a  dialog for each book item clicing and showing book item's info like  the name of book , the author, price of the book, year of its release and so on??

Comment: What do you want ? To show a dialog, when an item is clicked from the list ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case,Dialog should have separate xml file and java extending `DialogFragment` that gets inputs needed by dialog in `newInstance` method when creating an instance of that dialog .
Here is an example :

```
public class MyDialog extends DialogFragment
{
    private static final String KEY_AUTH = "author";
    private static final String KEY_PRICE = "price";
    private static final String KEY_YEAR = "year";
    private TextView txtauthor;
    private TextView txtprice ;
    private TextView txtyear ;


public static MyDialog newInstance(String author, String price, String year )
{
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(KEY_AUTH , author);
    args.putString(KEY_PRICE , price);
    args.putString(KEY_YEAR , year );

    MyDialog  d = new MyDialog ();
    d.setArguments(args);

    return d;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.my_dialoge_layout, null);

    initTextViews(view);

    MaterialAlertDialogBuilder builder = new MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(getContext());

    builder.setView(view);

    return builder.create();

 }


    private void initTextViews(View view)
    {

      //get views
        txtauthor= view.findViewById(R.id.txtauthor);
        txtprice = view.findViewById(R.id.txtprice );
        txtyear = view.findViewById(R.id.txtyear );
      //..and so on 

        //then set values 
        txtauthor.setText(getArguments().getString(KEY_AUTH ));
        txtprice.setText(getArguments().getString(KEY_PRICE ));
        txtyear.setText(getArguments().getString(KEY_YEAR ));
    }
}//end of  class MyDialog
```

and when ever you want to call dialog , call it by `newInstance` method mentioned above:

```
MyDialog dialog = MyDialog .newInstance("some author", "some price", "some year");
dialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "MyDialogTag");
```